# Web Audio API issues on mobile (can't seem to debug issues)

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, mobile-development

I have a website that's using an AnalyserNode for an audio element on a website. Works *perfectly* on desktop, but it doesn't show on mobile. I can't seem to figure out how to debug any issues. iOS simulator doesn't seem to show any errors either. Chrome's mobile emulator doesn't show any issues either.

How do you guys debug mobile issues with Web Audio API / Analyser?

Thanks in advance!

The site: [Pine Project Music](https://pineprojectmusic.com)

Comment: The site works fine for me with Chrome on Android.  For Chrome, you can visit chrome://inspect/#devices, find your phone, and look at the console logs and debug that way.

Comment: It's the visualizer when the song plays that doesn't show on mobile

Comment: I see the visualizer on my Pixel 2 phone, Chrome 81. (Gets a bit confused when I rotate my phone and change from portrait to landscape and back.)

Comment: Interesting. I don't have an android to test on. I need to add a listener to position the canvas but I can't test it on my phone. Ugh

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with iOS; I don't have any iOS devices.